# How to get all child nodes from DOMDocument?

Tags: php, domdocument, child-nodes

I have the following

```
$string = '<html><head></head><body><ul id="mainmenu">
  <li id="1">Hallo</li>
  <li id="2">Welt
    <ul>
      <li id="3">Sub Hallo</li>
      <li id="4">Sub Welt</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul></body></html>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);
```

now I want to have all `li` IDs inside one array.
I tried the following:

```
$all_li_ids = array();
$menu_nodes = $dom->getElementById('mainmenu')->childNodes;
foreach($menu_nodes as $li_node){
    if($li_node->nodeName=='li'){
        $all_li_ids[]=$li_node->getAttribute('id');         
    }
}
print_r($all_li_ids);
```

As you might see, this will print out `[1,2]`

How do I get all children (the subchildren as well `[1,2,3,4]`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My test doesn't return element by using `$dom->getElementById('mainmenu')`. But if your using does, do not use Xpath

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$ul = $xpath->query("//*[@id='mainmenu']")->item(0);

$all_li_ids = array();
// Find all inner li tags
$menu_nodes = $ul->getElementsByTagName('li');
foreach($menu_nodes as $li_node){
        $all_li_ids[]=$li_node->getAttribute('id');         
}
print_r($all_li_ids); 1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to add another foreach loop, ie:

```
foreach($menu_nodes as $node){
    if($node->nodeName=='li'){
        $all_li_ids[]=$node->getAttribute('id');         
    }
    foreach($node as $sub_node){
        if($sub_node->nodeName=='li'){
            $all_li_ids[]=$sub_node->getAttribute('id');         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works only with 1 level bellow the main ul; if you add another level of nesting, you will need 3rd loop and so on. Recursion will be better fit

Comment: True, but OP did not provide any evidence of extra nesting required.